# Doxygen + MikTex hbox + vbox badness

Tags: latex, doxygen, miktex

I have doxygen (with graphviz) outputting data to run Miktex to produce a refman.pdf.
When I run the tex make the output shows a *LOT* of

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line N
```

and quite a bit of

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 1163) has occurred while \output is active
```

Also with one run of the make.bat, tex appears to be run about 3-4 times each of the repeats

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Apparently the \hbox warning isn't unusual to see, but should I be concerned about seeing so many of them and seeing the \vbox warning and repeated tex runs?

(I'll warn you now, I haven't a notion of tex, I just let doxygen and eclox handle it all for me!)

Comment: Underfull `\hbox` and `\vbox` warnings will display sub-optimal text in the output. If it's not visible to you, then you can probably ignore it. See [What are Underfull `\hbox`es and `\vbox`es and how can I get rid of them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764) It's fine to rerun a couple of times, since (La)TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system works that way. It may take more than one compile for references to "settle". See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)

Comment: Thanks Werner, if you'd like to make your comment an answer as well I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: Based on what I can see, this question is actually purely (La)TeX-related. I'm flagging this for migration over to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underfull `\hbox` and `\vbox` warnings will display sub-optimal text in the output. If it's not visible to you, then you can probably ignore it. See [What are Underfull `\hbox`es and `\vbox`es and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764)

It's fine to rerun a couple of times, since (La)TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system works that way. In fact, with any form of cross-referencing you will have to compile at least twice on the first run as it may take more than one compile for references to "settle". See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).